# Load other pages when change my css style in C# or JS

Tags: c#, javascript, css, load

I have some scroller  menu like :

```
<div id="panel" class="scroller">
   <div class="scroller-view" style = left:-100>      
    <span class="item "></span>
    <a href="/123" class="item" style=""><img src="/images.png">123</span></a>
    <a href="/456" class="item" style=""><img src="/images1.png">456</span></a>
    <a href="/789" class="item" style=""><img src="/images2.png">789</span></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need when  `style = left:change from 0 to -300` load other class 
like:

```
when left:0 load class 123;
when left :-100 load class 456;
when left :-285 load class 789;
```

How I do that with c# ?

Comment: Are you building a image carousel?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Jquery solution. But you need to set a ID in Div.

```
 //Document Ready event
 $(document).ready(function () {
     if ($("#scroller-view").css("left") == "-100px") {
         $("#scroller-view").removeClass("scroller-view");
         $("#scroller-view").addClass("Class1");
     } else if ...
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are specifying the **left** by a stuation. For example `Student.Age < 10`, then `left =0` and `Student.Age >10` than `left =-100`.
You are specifying this stuations in c# code.
And now you have two selection,

1. You can render your div panel in c# code.
2. if you are using MVC, you can keep your left varibles in ViewBag.Left dynamic varible.

Comment: Tnks
How i do that with 1 selection?
so if (class == 123)
     style="left:-100"
   if (class == 456)
      style="left:-286"
   if (class == 789)
      style="left:-356"?

Comment: You can use TagBuilder    TagBuilder label = new TagBuilder("label");
    label.AddCssClass("control-label");
    label.InnerHtml = propObj.LabelCaption;